# retrieving data from firestore (flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how can i  read a single field data from firestore and store it to a variable?

```dart
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
```

```dart
            Container(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(stream: users , builder: (BuildContext context        ,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
               if (snapshot.hasData){
                 return Text("error");
               }
               if (snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
                 return Text('loading data');
               }
               final data=snapshot.requireData;
               return ListView.builder(
                 itemCount: data.size,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index){
                   return Text(data.docs[index]['username']);
                 } ,

               );

              },),
            )
```

[image]

Comment: are you trying to get current user data or any[first] user data

Comment: yes ,the current user data

Comment: can you include an image of your console db screenshot how you;ve structured

Comment: https://ic.wampi.ru/2023/02/25/elv.png

Comment: ok you are using `admin` , you might prefer putting uid,

Comment: yeah i want to retrieve the data field value called 'username' in he document named 'admin'

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```dart
final data = snapshot.data as Map?;

return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: data?.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final map = data?[index];
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("${map?['username']}"),
        Text("${map?['password']}"),
      ],
    );
  },
);
},
```